# Do we use singular or plural countable noun with word "Any"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Do we use singular or plural countable noun with word "Any"?

For example:

> She hasn't any **friend**

or

> She hasn't any **friends**

which of the above is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Any is used to show indefinite quantities / number in questions and negative sentences.

I don't have any friends. Is correct.

Other examples..
1. Have you got any sense ?
2. It does not make any sense.
3. There isn't any ink in this pen.
4. Is he of any use to you ?
5. Anybody willing to accompany me there ?